# Nginx how to get an SSL certificate for a Django app

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

I have a Digitalocean Droplet running Ubuntu 16.04. it's all configured and I can access my site. However I have been struggling to setup the SSL certificate (i am new to webserver administration).

I have the CA signed `certificate.crt` and `private.key` in a folder called `/var/certs/`.

Djang app `settings.py` has the following enabled:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/user/project_folder;

    }

    location / {

        include proxy_params;

        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project_folder/project.sock;

    }


}
```

I have done a lot of research on the Digitalocean site, here and google for how to configure Nginx to use a SSL certificate with a Django but its proving to be quite complicated. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: I was having trouble with this in the past.  Not using what you are using but I had an Ubuntu server and needed an SSL cert.  I had the best luck with  the letsEncrypt project.  If you already have a cert this may not matter to you, but you can still check it out

Comment: https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2016/10/07/securing-django-lets-encrypt/  check this out

Comment: I was able to do the http - https redirect by following [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/http-https-redirect-positive-ssl-on-nginx). Once again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add listener on port 443 for https. 
You nginx configuration will look like this. 
No specific changes required on django app as such

```
server {

    listen 443;

    server_name example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_certificate /var/certs/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/certs/private.key;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/user/project_folder;

    }

    location / {

        include proxy_params;

        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project_folder/project.sock;

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly when i uses `https://www.example.com`. Now when i just use `www.example.co.uk` or `example.co.uk` i am directed to the nginx welcome page, do i now have to somehow redirect http to use https?

Comment: Yes set up a listener on port 80 and a redirection. You can google that up or i can answer that as well in a seperate question.